# Normal Work of RPi 3B+

Tags: pi-3, pi-3b+, activity-led, act, power-light

I am newbie and i want to understand  watching only on indicators, is Rpi 3 B+ work quite well?
I mean, are green and red lights should glowing both permanently together or red light can glows permanently and green light can fades meanwhile? 
Also, how can i understand does raspberry 3B+ work before installing drivers for my TFT(while display is white)

Comment: Maybe someone else will have more luck, but I cannot understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Brick, i want to undestand does my Rpi work watching on indicators. Is it normal when red light always glows and green light fades periodically meanwhile?

Comment: Or both green and red lights must glow all the time together if Rpi works

Comment: You can't from the lights find out whether it works well. You may be able to find out if something is seriously wrong.

Comment: @RalfFriedl, is statement that both permanently glowing of green and red lights is normal work of Rpi without something wrong?

Comment: Or green light shouldn`t glows permanently to understand there is no problems with RPi work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red LED is the power indicator, it should be on whenever you have your pi plugged in. The green LED is the sd card access indicator; it goes on when the pi is accessing the sd card (which is like its hard drive). When you plug the pi in, the red light should turn on and then the green light should turn on. After that, the green light will flicker and fade on and off as you use your pi. **That is normal behavior**.

You have not told us enough about your TFT so I cannot answer your second question. Please edit your question and add more details, such as the TFT model, what you have tried, what isn't working, and how you think it should work. Thanks!